# What is the best practice to implement optional consuming of ownership?

Tags: rust

Assume I have the following structure

```
struct Test {
    value : i32,
}
```

and I implement the following method for it

```
impl Test {
    fn take_ownership(self) -> Option<Self> {
       if self.value >= 0 {
           Some(self)
       } else {
           None
       }
    }
}
```

I am good with the consumption of the ownership in the case when `value` is greater than `0`, but how can I rewrite the code so that the ownership is not consumed in the case `None` is returned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return a `Result` with the failed ownership instance as the error type:

```rust
struct Test {
    value: i32,
}

impl Test {
    fn take_ownership(self) -> Result<i32, Self> {
       if self.value >= 0 {
           Ok(self.value)
       } else {
           Err(self)
       }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=232cfc15239cf5565a50b34dad843277)

Notice that this still consumes `self`, but you can recover it afterwards.

Also remember that you can always get an `Option` from a `Result` later on:

```rust
fn main() {
    let t = Test { value: 10 };
    let value = t.take_ownership().ok();
    println!("{value:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3ec4ee289f8f60c1146b64abc158c67e)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to take ownership of the `self` object, you can try to pass and recieve it by reference:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5f92c1ea1a69e0da1e153bd8625a5a53

```
impl Test {
    fn take_ownership(&self) -> Option<&Self> {
       if self.value >= 0 {
           Some(self)
       } else {
           None
       }
    }
}
```